# How to update only modified values in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter for building a website. The website has an option called 'update record' which allows the user to update 50 different values. The update page has the old value along with an empty text box for the user to enter the new value. Updating the whole record even though the user has not actually updated anything makes no sense (website uses MySQL database). I've tried using hidden form field with the original value and tried to update only modified fields. Though it is working fine, the process looks so lengthy every time comparing the old value with the new one and updating only if there is a change.

Is there a better way to do this (with or without using codeigniter)? Just curious to know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the approach. put the old value in textbox and let users change there. If it is same (i.e. user hasn't touched it), MySQL notices this and does not update it.

Comment: @itachi but I'm maintaining a log table for all the updates. How do i update the log table only with the modified values?

Comment: lol you should have mentioned it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the post array and remove any entries that don't have a value for updated (which would mean the input was submitted empty).

Then you could only update the modified records

I don't know how code igniter passes the post array into the controller after form submission but you could do something like

```
<?php
foreach ($postData as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        unset($postData[$key]);
    }
}
```

The only place this would fall down is if you legitimately want to store an empty record as the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

I use javascript to do filter only updated values

```
1 - I use hashes.js to calculate a sha1 when page loaded. store it in hidden or just a variable, or you can do sha in the server.
2 - I also do a snapshot of the form in array when page loaded. I put all my input in one class and use jQuery('forminputs').each to put them in array.
3 - when user click submit, first I do another snapshot of the form as No. 2 and compare the hash. if the hash diff, I use php.js get the updated value php.array_diff_assoc(newsnapshot, oldsnapshot). and post this to server.
```

Though these seems like a lot of computation, but in fact it is not slow at all in firefox or chrome(never try IE).